# COSM Trigger extracting JSON values using C# from an HTTP Post

Tags: c#, json, triggers, cosm

Trying to receive COSM Trigger HTTP Post via a C# RESTful service, not receiving the alert. I took the COSM API JSON payload and used it from a test client - that worked. When I setup my feed and either try the debug trigger test, or just force the trigger to fire normally, my REST service doesn't get called. If I try any form of test client the service processes the JSON POST just fine.

C# service is here:

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "cosm", 
        RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    string CosmAlert(CosmTrigger data);
```

Where CosmTrigger is my class mirroring the [COSM Trigger fields](https://cosm.com/docs/v2/trigger/).

My COSM feed is [here](https://cosm.com/feeds/123312).

I'm starting from the COSM portal to fire a trigger, Twitter based trigger works fine, the  HTTP Post to my URL isn't. How to debug this?

Comment: This operation contract is very standard and working when I upload the Cosm document sample data as the triggier would, as an HTTP POST. Could someone post a C# service contract that is working from receiving a Cosm trigger?

Comment: I made an empty method and that got called. I also sent the Cosm Trigger API data from my own client program and that was received fine. There's something the Cosm hosting service is sending that's not consistent with what the Microsoft C# standard operation contract is looking for. Probably the Cosm service is sending a different payload from the V2 doc example payload, and it's non-standard as far as the C# Operation Contract is concerned. What could it be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tested and working code -

```
[OperationContract]  
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST",  
BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest,  
UriTemplate = "cosm")]  
string cosmStream(Stream body);
```

Answer (score 1):

A Cosm trigger currently doesn't send triggers as a JSON body, it actually sends a URL encoded request with the JSON trigger body encoded as a parameter called 'body'.

Using http://requestb.in on a test trigger, and viewing the raw output this shows the basic request looks like this:

```
POST /103s0dh1 HTTP/1.1
X-Request-Id: e05e9d699edbd5f584fc491cf9416df747be4df4
User-Agent: Cosm Deliverator (Axino/0.3.02) - https://cosm.com
Host: requestb.in
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 918
Connection: close

body=%7B%22id%22%3A7443%2C%22url%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fapi.cosm.com%2Fv2%2Ftriggers%2F7443%22%2C%22type%22%3A%22lt%22%2C%22threshold_value%22%3A%2220%22%2C%22timestamp%22%3A%222013-04-14T09%3A50%3A47.590044Z%22%2C%22environment%22%3A%7B%22id%22%3A57346%2C%22feed%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fapi.cosm.com%2Fv2%2Ffeeds%2F57346%22%2C%22title%22%3A%22Macbook+Battery+Level%22%2C%22description%22%3A%22%22%2C%22private%22%3Afalse%2C%22location%22%3A%7B%22lat%22%3Anull%2C%22lon%22%3Anull%2C%22name%22%3A%22%22%7D%7D%2C%22triggering_datastream%22%3A%7B%22id%22%3A%22battery%22%2C%22url%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fapi.cosm.com%2Fv2%2Ffeeds%2F57346%2Fdatastreams%2Fbattery%22%2C%22at%22%3A%222013-04-14T09%3A50%3A02.406927Z%22%2C%22value%22%3A%7B%22max_value%22%3A1724.0%2C%22min_value%22%3A0.0%2C%22value%22%3A%2226.28%22%7D%2C%22units%22%3A%7B%22type%22%3Anull%2C%22symbol%22%3A%22%25%22%2C%22label%22%3Anull%7D%7D%2C%22debug%22%3Atrue%7D
```

I'm not a C# expert unfortunately but I suspect the problem is something to do with the service not being configured to extract the JSON body from a standard urlencoded request body, but perhaps this might give a clue to how to figure out what is going wrong for someone who does know C#.